# Removing bullets from radio buttons when using Django forms

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to remove the bullets that are showing up beside the radio button when rendering a form.

My template is as follows:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" class="uniForm">
<fieldset class="inlineLabels">
{% csrf_token %}
<br>
<h6>Library Type</h6>
{{ formtoaddmodel.type }}
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The type field is a `TypedChoiceField`, which produced radio buttons for the choices, but the problem is it puts a bullet point before each radio button.

To remove the bullets, I read that you need to include . However, I'm not sure where to put this. When I do this in the CSS it affects everywhere in my site where I use bulleted lists. 
Is there a way to do this in the template to over-ride the CSS, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have you tried using CSS like this?

```
fieldset.inlineLabels ul {list-style:none}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with bullets showing up next to radio buttons for flask forms. Using the solution for bullets in flask from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591202/how-to-make-a-radiofield-in-flask), I was able to get rid of the bullets like this:

```
<p>
   Certification:
   {{form.certification(style="list-style:none")}}
</p>
```