# How to make a RadioField in Flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a form with a TextField, FileField, and I want to add a RadioField.

I'd like to have a radio field with two options, where the user can only select one. I'm following the example of the two previous forms that work.

My forms.py looks like this

```
    from flask import Flask, request
    from werkzeug import secure_filename
    from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField, BooleanField, FileField, file_required,         RadioField
    from flask.ext.wtf import Required
    class ImageForm(Form):
        name = TextField('name', validators = [Required()])
        fileName = FileField('fileName', validators=[file_required()])
        certification = RadioField('certification', choices = ['option1', 'option2'])
```

In my views.py file I have

```
form = myForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    name = form.name.data
    fileName = secure_filename(form.fileName.file.filename)
    certification = form.certification.data
```

In my .html file I have

```
     {% block content %}
     <h1>Simple Form</h1>
     <form action="" method="post" name="simple" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {{form.hidden_tag()}}
         <p>
             Name:
             {{form.name(size=80)}}
         </p>
         <p>
             Upload a file
             {{form.fileName()}}
         </p>
         <p>
             Certification:
             {{form.certification()}}
         </p>
         <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
     </form>
     {% endblock %}
```

I can't seem to find examples online of someone using a radio button form. I found a description of RadioField here http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html

When I try to visit the my form page I get the DEBUG error "**ValueError: too many values to unpack**"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the forms.py the RadioField needs to look like this

```
    RadioField('Label', choices=[('value','description'),('value_two','whatever')])
```

Where the options are 'description' and 'whatever' with the submitted values being 'value' an 'value_two' respectively.

Comment: I want to make one of the choices checked by default. Is it possible ?

Comment: Make one choice checked by default (@f.ashouri): `RadioField('Label', choices=[('value','description'),('value_two','whatever')], default='value_two')` - sorry 8 years after the event ... hope its useful to someone

Comment: @Siecje Why is this syntax required?

Answer (score 10):

form.certification() won't work. You need to iterate over the values in the template:

Replace:

```
{{ form.certification() }}
```

with:

```
{% for subfield in form.certification %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
    <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Okay, I have that in my .html file, but I am still getting the Value Error. What should my forms.py contain? I currently have 

        certification = RadioField('certification', choices = ['option1', 'option2'])